# LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'cv.lib'

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, mex

i have been stuck with this problem since yesterday, and i cant figure it out.
im already following the steps from this pdf
http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21818-opencv-and-mex-files-quick-guide

and this is my mexopts.bat looks like :

> @echo off
>   rem MSVC100OPTS.BAT
>   rem
>   rem    Compile and link options used for building MEX-files
>   rem    using the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler version 10.0
>   rem
>   rem    $Revision: 1.1.6.4.2.1 $  $Date: 2012/07/12 13:53:59 $
>   rem    Copyright 2007-2009 The MathWorks, Inc.
>   rem
>   rem StorageVersion: 1.0
>   rem C++keyFileName: MSVC100OPTS.BAT
>   rem C++keyName: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010
>   rem C++keyManufacturer: Microsoft
>   rem C++keyVersion: 10.0
>   rem C++keyLanguage: C++
>   rem C++keyLinkerName: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010
>   rem C++keyLinkerVersion: 10.0
>   rem
>   rem ********************************************************************
>   rem General parameters
>   rem ********************************************************************
>   set MATLAB=%MATLAB%
>   set OPENCVDIR=D:\OPENCV\opencv\build
>   set VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
>   set VCINSTALLDIR=%VSINSTALLDIR%\VC
>   rem In this case, LINKERDIR is being used to specify the location of the SDK
>   set LINKERDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\
>   set PATH=%VCINSTALLDIR%\bin\amd64;%VCINSTALLDIR%\bin;%VCINSTALLDIR%\VCPackages;%VSINSTALLDIR%\Common7\IDE;%VSINSTALLDIR%\Common7\Tools;%LINKERDIR%\bin\x64;%LINKERDIR%\bin;%MATLAB_BIN%;%PATH%
>   set INCLUDE=%OPENCVDIR%\include;%VCINSTALLDIR%\INCLUDE;%VCINSTALLDIR%\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;%LINKERDIR%\include;%INCLUDE%
>   set 
> LIB=%OPENCVDIR%\x64\vc10\lib;%OPENCVDIR%\x64\vc10\bin;%VCINSTALLDIR%\LIB\amd64;%VCINSTALLDIR%\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64;%LINKERDIR%\lib\x64;%MATLAB%\extern\lib\win64;%LIB%
>   set MW_TARGET_ARCH=win64
>   rem ********************************************************************
>   rem Compiler parameters
>   rem ********************************************************************
>   set COMPILER=cl
>   set COMPFLAGS=/c /GR /W3 /EHs /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0 /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE /nologo /MD
>   set OPTIMFLAGS=/O2 /Oy- /DNDEBUG
>   set DEBUGFLAGS=/Z7
>   set NAME_OBJECT=/Fo
>   rem ********************************************************************
>   rem Linker parameters
>   rem ********************************************************************
>   set LIBLOC=%MATLAB%\extern\lib\win64\microsoft
>   set LINKER=link
>   set LINKFLAGS=/dll /export:%ENTRYPOINT% /LIBPATH:"%OPENCVDIR%" cv.lib highgui.lib cvaux.lib cxcore.lib  /LIBPATH:"%LIBLOC%" libmx.lib libmex.lib libmat.lib /MACHINE:X64 kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /nologo /manifest /incremental:NO /implib:"%LIB_NAME%.x" /MAP:"%OUTDIR%%MEX_NAME%%MEX_EXT%.map"
>   set LINKOPTIMFLAGS=
>   set LINKDEBUGFLAGS=/debug /PDB:"%OUTDIR%%MEX_NAME%%MEX_EXT%.pdb"
>   set LINK_FILE=
>   set LINK_LIB=
>   set NAME_OUTPUT=/out:"%OUTDIR%%MEX_NAME%%MEX_EXT%"
>   set RSP_FILE_INDICATOR=@
>   rem ********************************************************************
>   rem Resource compiler parameters
>   rem ********************************************************************
>   set RC_COMPILER=rc /fo "%OUTDIR%mexversion.res"
>   set RC_LINKER=
>   set POSTLINK_CMDS=del "%LIB_NAME%.x" "%LIB_NAME%.exp"
>   set POSTLINK_CMDS1=mt -outputresource:"%OUTDIR%%MEX_NAME%%MEX_EXT%;2" -manifest "%OUTDIR%%MEX_NAME%%MEX_EXT%.manifest"
>   set POSTLINK_CMDS2=del "%OUTDIR%%MEX_NAME%%MEX_EXT%.manifest"
>   set POSTLINK_CMDS3=del "%OUTDIR%%MEX_NAME%%MEX_EXT%.map"

but i got an error like this :

> LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'cv.lib'
>
> C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2012B\BIN\MEX.PL: 
>   
>  Error: Link of 'displayimage.mexw64' failed.

Please help me to solve this, and thanks in advance.
by the way im using Matlab R2012b and OpenCV 2.4.9

Comment: See http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/19889-help-with-linking-with-mex.

Answer (score 0):

according to this site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6b12xkc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx., the particular error code results when the file can not be found.

Also, I *think* that I gotten this error message when I accidentally mixed 32-bit and 64-bit libraries, but that is just a vague recollection.

Answer (score 0):

those missing 3 opencv libs were used with like opencv 1.0. long time ago. but no more.

```
set LINKFLAGS=/dll /export:%ENTRYPOINT% /LIBPATH:"%OPENCVDIR%" cv.lib highgui.lib cvaux.lib cxcore.lib
```

the current names of the opencv_libs are like opencv_core248.lib, opencv_highgui248.lib, etc. look inside that %OPENCVDIR%\x64\vc10\lib folder and instead add what you find there.